# Adding Across Arrays

Tags: php

I structured the item information in an unorthodox way, it is stored in three different arrays and are related by the key. I am looking to Sum the Quantities by ItemID.

```
   1. Array #1 ItemID
        $_SESSION["item_id"][] 
             1 => 1, 2 => 1, 3 =>2
   2. Array #2 Size 
        $_SESSION["size"][]   
             1 => S, 2 => L, 3 =>S
   3. Array #3 Quantity 
        $_SESSION["count"][]
             1 => 250, 2 =>750, 3=>250
```

The result should be as follows:

ItemID # 1 --> Quantity 1000

ItemID # 2 --> Quantity 250

Could someone could help me with a function ?

Comment: State what have you tried so far. Or do you think that we will build one for you?

Comment: No, I don't but I did try...it's just probably not worth posting it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, you have the following array in `$_SESSION`:

```
$_SESSION['item_id'] = array(1, 1, 2);
$_SESSION['size'] = array('S', 'L', 'S');
$_SESSION['count'] = array(250, 750, 250);
```

> NOTE: the following answer take assumption that array length in those 3 SESSION value are equal.

You will need to create new array to store the result:

```
$newArrayResult = array();
```

After that, you will need to do `for...each` loop to extract currently accessed key:

```
foreach($_SESSION['item_id'] as $key => $value){
    //the logic goes here
}
```

Next, we will use item_id as our array key in $newArrayResult. To do that, we will need to check first, if it is already defined. If not, create the key with default value `0`. We do the checking by using built in function called `array_key_exists`. This way, we will avoid running into undefined key index error.

```
if(!array_key_exists($value, $newArrayResult)){
    $newArrayResult[$value] = 0;
}
```

After we have the key for $newArrayResult, next step would be to simply store count value into it:

```
$newArrayResult[$value] += $_SESSION['count'][$key];
```

Done. Print the result to test:

```
print_r($newArrayResult);
```

Here is the whole code again, for you to copy-paste. Don't forget to read and understand the above flow first:

```
$_SESSION['item_id'] = array(1, 1, 2);
$_SESSION['size'] = array('S', 'L', 'S');
$_SESSION['count'] = array(250, 750, 250);

$newArrayResult = array();
foreach($_SESSION['item_id'] as $key => $value){
    if(!array_key_exists($value, $newArrayResult)){
        $newArrayResult[$value] = 0;
    }
    $newArrayResult[$value] += $_SESSION['count'][$key];
}

print_r($newArrayResult);
```

Comment: Okay thanks. It's been a while since I've played with PHP, and I'm not particularly versed in playing with arrays. To check my understanding, if I wanted to get the AggregateQty. I would do this:                 for($i=0; $i<count($_SESSION["item_id"]); $i++)
        {
          foreach($newArrayResultas $key => $value)
          {
            if($value = $_SESSION["item_id"][$i])
            {
              //use the aggregated count by itemID for the discount
              $aggregateQty = $value;
            }
          }
        }

Comment: have you tried the code I gave you? it is a stand-alone script. Just copy-paste it to text files and run it. You should be able to grasp the basic idea about it.